# Add-on not available on shareable link sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a Google Apps domain. The domain has a sheet with a Google Apps Script add-on. We have to share this sheet with people outside our organisation. The add-on is used to refresh the data displayed in the spreadsheet.

When someone who isn't logged in opens the shared link, the add-on is not available for them. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to get around the restriction that requires the user to be logged in.

- Your add-on modifies spreadsheet contents on behalf of the user.
- That operation requires authorization from the user.
- Only logged-in users can grant authorization.

Reference: [Develop Add-ons for Google Sheets, Docs, and Forms - Authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#authorization)

A separate web service that ran as you, say, and was accessible to "Everyone, including anonymous", *could* modify a spreadsheet without requiring a user to be logged in. You could not make this part of the Sheets UI, though.